# Q: How Can I use data flow with ActiveMQ in Esper?

Tags: activemq-classic, esper

I am Learning Esper, and I want to learn about Data flow more.
I used ActiveMQ, so I want to using data flow and EsperIO to connect ActiveMQ.
I know about AMQP using EsperIO and ActiveMQ, so I hope that is work.

but my source is got error and they didn't find ActiveMQ. So, How I can Connect with ActiveMQ and EsperIO via Data Flow EPL clause?

bellows, my Error text :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/rabbitmq/client/Connection;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.espertech.esper.util.JavaClassHelper.findFieldInternal(JavaClassHelper.java:1799)
    at com.espertech.esper.util.JavaClassHelper.findAnnotatedFields(JavaClassHelper.java:1784)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.injectObjectProperties(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:338)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.instantiateOperator(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:320)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.instantiateOperators(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:294)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.instantiateInternal(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.instantiate(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:126)
    at com.espertech.esper.dataflow.core.DataFlowServiceImpl.instantiate(DataFlowServiceImpl.java:113)
    at Esper.EventReciveThread.run(EventReciveThread.java:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and bellows, is my EPL code :

```
"create dataflow writeAMQP EventBusSource -> outstream<Event>{} AMQPSink(outstream){host:'localhost', queueName: 'testQueue', collector:{class:'ObjectToAMQPCollectorSerializable'}}
```

Comment: why does your exception trace show rabbitMQ?

Comment: looks like your classpath doesn't have some key rabbit jar files

Comment: Please note that ActiveMQ support AMQP 1.0 while RabbitMQ support <1.0 versions of AMQP (unless you go for the plugin). Never the less, you seem to have some dependency trouble to start with..

Comment: I found some solution and try it, but EsperIO using AMQP 0.9.1 and ActiveMQ using 1.0. Version Mismatch. so I fail that....